# Unable to make a PATCH request using radio buttons in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, json, api, fetch-api, patch

I am trying to add in a list of tasks and want to change them to either "Complete" or "Not Complete" using radio buttons and then updating it to send a PATCH request to the data to update. When I press update nothing changes on the data.

This is the code I have for this page:

`

```
function ProjectDetails() {
  const [WaxProcedure, setWaxProcedure] = useState("");
  const { id } = useParams();
  const {
    data: project,
    error,
    isPending,
  } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/ProjectsData/${id}`);
  const history = useNavigate();

  const handleClickDelete = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/ProjectsData/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    }).then(() => {
      history("/");
    });
  };

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/ProjectsData/${id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        body: JSON.stringify(project),
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      response.json();
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="project-details">
      {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      {project && (
        <article>
          <h1>{project.Customer}</h1>
          <h2>
            {project.Part} {project.Description}
          </h2>
          <h2>{project.Tool}</h2>
          <div>Project Status: {project.Stage}</div>
          <p>Lead engineer: {project.Engineer}</p>
          <div className="procedure-list">
            <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
              Wax: <p>{WaxProcedure}</p>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="waxprocedure"
                value="Not Complete"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setWaxProcedure(e.target.value)}
              />
              Not Complete
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="waxprocedure"
                value="Complete"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setWaxProcedure(e.target.value)}
              />
              Complete
              <button type="submit" onClick={handleUpdate}>
                Update
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" onClick={handleClickDelete}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </article>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`
Any ideas why the data won't update? I am new to this and spent a long time trying to find an answer.

I have tried the patch request on Postman and this worked too, so nothing wrong with the request.

Answer (score 0):

remove "onsubmit" from form tag and remove type="submit" from both buttons and pass "project" parameter to handleupdate method

Comment: removed "onsubmit from form but couldn't remove type="submit" as I was getting an error. Made no change though I'm afraid

Comment: you cannot keep type="submit" and "onclick" on same button

Comment: Thanks Sudip, but it's not the root cause of my problem. It's still not changing my data when submitting the update. Could it be an async problem?